# Spring: Setting up locale

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization

I've setup Spring as specified in the following guide: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/basic-webapp-internationalization-spring-config.html

If I was to append ?locale=fr, for example, to the end of an URL the locale will change to French.

However, in my case, I want to set the locale when the user logs in as this information is associated with their profile. I've tried to use localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("fr")) (where localeResolver is an instance of SessionLocaleResolver) to specify the locale however this doesn't have any effect.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Am I approaching this issue in the correct way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

localeResolver.setLocale works fine for me, try something like this:

applicationContext

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="messages/messages" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />
```

my_page.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><spring:message code="my.message"/></p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

\src\main\resources\messages\messages.properties

> my.message=Message (default language)

\src\main\resources\messages\messages_en.properties

> my.message=Message in English

\src\main\resources\messages\messages_fr.properties

> my.message=Message in French

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString("fr"));
        return "my_page";
    }
}
```

With this code I get "Message in French", if I change "fr" to "en" I get "Message in English", and without setLocale call I get "Message (default language)". Changing StringUtils.parseLocaleString("fr") to new Locale("fr") gives the same results.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend try to set up default locale as:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
     <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr_FR" />
 </bean>
```

Some helpful info is in blog post [Configuring locale switching with Spring MVC 3](http://templth.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/configuring-locale-switching-with-spring-mvc-3/).

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class i18nConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Bean
 public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
     SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
     Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
     sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);
     return sessionLocaleResolver;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably take a look at Spring Roo project. There is an internationalization add on from Spring which is being used in Spring Roo which enables quick switching of Locale within a Spring Web application automatically generated from Roo.

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine that the locale has not been set? If you expect, the correct locale to be present in `HttpServletRequest`, this isn't true — its value is handled by the servlet container and is therefore immutable. Instead, you should rely that Spring will inject a proper value to a method parameter with class `Locale` in your controller. Another way to obtain the locale is by using `RequestContextUtils.getLocale(HttpServletRequest request)` directly.

Comment: I'm trying to set the locale programatically. The messages are still in English. I use the ?locale=fr method instead, the messages are now being loaded as French.

Comment: please provide your code of how you retrieve the current user's locale from the environment